# Swift - Is any local database like SQLite that allows multiple connections?

Tags: ios, swift, database, sqlite, local

I'm using [stephencelis SQLite](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md) in my project and it works fine, but when I accede to the database twice at the same time, it blows up.

I know I can avoid that using threads making the second run seconds after the first, but, I wonder if there is any other way or other library to allows get multiple connections in the local database?

Comment: Why not just use CoreData?

Comment: I'm not sure how CoreData works; I want to get the data which was previously saved, even if a few days have passed, and examine them to export them. It is possible with CoreData or Realm?

Comment: CoreData is the built-in data persistence library. It has been part of iOS since the beginning. It is backed by an SQLite DB. If you want to store data locally on iOS this should be the first place you go. You should check out tutorials on raywenderlich.com

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at realm:
https://realm.io

The syntax is easy, support is great, and the library is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a SQL based solution steer clear of Realm, it is not SQL based.

One option I have tried and tested and can recommend is SharkORM, it is based on SQLite and is thread safe, meaning that you can access the DB from two different places simultaneously as long as you wrap the calls in an `SRKTransaction`. You can get Shark [here](http://www.sharkorm.com).

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [GRDB.swift](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift). It takes concurrency a little more seriously than other SQLite libraries: http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift#concurrency.

See also:

- [Four different ways to handle SQLite concurrency](https://medium.com/@gwendal.roue/four-different-ways-to-handle-sqlite-concurrency-db3bcc74d00e#.odp1k81up)
- [How to build an iOS application with SQLite and GRDB.swift](https://medium.com/@gwendal.roue/how-to-build-an-ios-application-with-sqlite-and-grdb-swift-d023a06c29b3#.ophuzevn9)